# Notation: the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_\tau^+$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I'm reading a probability textbook on stochastic processes (Jochen Wengenroth's "Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie", de Gruyter 2008) and the following notation: "$\mathcal{F}_\tau^+$" came up in the statement of one of the theorems, without this notation having been defined previously in the book. If this is a standard notation, I'd appreciate it if someone could give me a formal definition of it. If it's not a standard notation, and someone has a guess as to what it might mean, please let me know. Thanks.

Here is the statement of the theorem featuring this notation (translated from German, p. 144).

> ***Theorem 7.14 (Strong Lévy property)*** Let $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Lévy process adapted to the filtration $\mathcal{F}$ and let $\tau$ be a real-valued $\mathcal{F}$ stopping time. Then the following process $Y_t \equiv X_{\tau + t} - X_\tau$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_\tau^+$ and satisfies $Y \overset{d}{=} X$.

And here is the definition of a similar notation defined previously in the same chapter (p. 142).

> Given a filtration $\mathcal{F} = (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$, the *right-continuous* filtration $\mathcal{F}^+$ is defined as follows: $\mathcal{F}^+_t \equiv \bigcap_{s > t} \mathcal{F}_s$.

Comment: So you have the definition (this is a standard notation). The only (important) difference in the theorem is that $\tau$ is a stopping-time so this is a random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wengenroth uses the more explicit version of $\mathcal F_\tau^+$ in the paragraph preceding theorem 7.12 on page 142, namely $(\mathcal F^+)_\tau$. $\mathcal F_\tau^+$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal F^+$ events before $\tau$, that is

> $$ \mathcal F_\tau^+ = \{A \subseteq  \Omega \mid A \cap \{\tau \le t\} \in \mathcal F_t^+, t \ge 0\} $$